# Regex.IsMatch to MatchRegex in FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, fluent-assertions

I looked at the [documentation](https://fluentassertions.com/strings/) and there were methods e.g.`Match`, `MatchRegex`, etc., so I decided to improve the commented statement below and replace `Regex.IsMatch` with `MatchRegex`. However, I'm getting a compile-time error. How do I fix it?

It's a `List<Product>` that shouldn't contain anything that could be matched to the following regex: `@"<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>"`.

```cs
//actual.Products.Should().NotContain(p => Regex.IsMatch(p.Description, @"<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>"));

actual.Products.Should().NotContain(p =>
    p.Description.Should().MatchRegex(@"<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>")); // compile-time error
```

Comment: What is the compile-time error?

Comment: @Dai, `Cannot convert expression type 'FluentAssertions.AndConstraint<FluentAssertions.Primitives.StringAssertions>' to return type 'bool`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
  actual.Products.Should().AllSatisfy(p =>
        p.Description.Should().NotMatchRegex(@"<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>"));
```